# No puedo asignar variables utilizando el metodo subscribe() para FireBase en Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, método

Estoy intentando recopilar los datos de mi base de datos NoSQL de FireBase utilizando el metodo subscribe, pero no me acaba de funcionar.

**services.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
//Archivo json
import _reportes from "../archivos json/reportes.json";
import _vacio from "../archivos json/vacio.json";
//Exportador pdf
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
//firebase

import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesService {
  @Input() reportes
  coleccionReporte: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reporte>;
  reportess: Observable<Reporte[]>;
  reportesMargis;
  reportesDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Reporte>;
  ColeccionDeReportes;
  Reporte;

  constructor(public firebase:AngularFirestore) { 
    this.reportess = firebase.collection('reporte').valueChanges();
     console.log(this.reportes)   
  }

  getReporters(){
    return this.reportes
  }
```

**datos-in.component.ts (constructor):**

```
constructor(private reportesServices:ServicesService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.reportesServices.reportess.subscribe(
     data => 
     this.test2 = data
   );
}
```

Cuando quiero recopilarlo en la aplicacion de Angular, me sale el siguiente error (el "undefined" es por console log del firebase del servicio):

[image: Error al recopilar]

Comment: En tu service tienes un atributo declarado  como `reportess` al que nunca asignas nada, es normal que sea `undefined`.

Comment: @PabloLozano Perdona, lo habia editado mal, el atributo lo utilizaba para asignarle lo que cogia del FireBase. Ya esta cambiado.

Comment: ¿el resto de apariciones de `this.reportes` son también erratas?

Comment: No, lo puse en el console.log para verificar que la información pasada se metia dentro del atributo.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo claro lo que intentas hacer, porque no le veo mucho sentido al código, pero te comento los errores que veo:

```
constructor(public firebase:AngularFirestore) { 
   // subscribe no devuelve un Observable, sino una Subscription
   this.reportess = firebase.collection('reporte').snapshotChanges()
       .subscribe(data => this.reportes = data.length);
    // this.reportes siempre será undefined aquí: te has suscrito pero la ejecución es asíncrona
    console.log(this.reportes)
}
```

Por los errores de consola asumo que tienes un método getReportes en el Service que también está fallando, pero sin ver el código no puedo comentar mucho más.

Comment: Mi compñaero me habia enviado el codigo mal, acabo de editarlo para tenerlo como lo tenemos ahora. Perdona por las molestias.

Comment: Podrías añadir una *s* a `console.log(this.reportes)` y comprobar que estáis obteniendo un observable? No veo cómo obtener un undefined más tarde si el servicio se inicializa así